# Why are my controllers not being exported?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to write a file that will pull in, and export all my controllers automatically for an Express project. For some reason it won't work. I'm still pretty new to node and Express. Here's the code:

```js
// export all controllers

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const controllers = new Object();

(async () => {
    fs.readdir('./controllers', async (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        await files.forEach(file => {
            if (file !== 'index.js') {
                const i = path.basename(file).indexOf('.');
                const fn = path.basename(file).slice(0, i); 
                controllers[fn] = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
            }
        });
    });
})();

module.exports = controllers;
```

If I log my exports to the console I get an empty object, even though I know the code works otherwise. What this should do is require all the controller classes and then export them in an object with the names of the classes as the keys and the classes themselves as the values.

Comment: If this works at all, I'd be surprised, exports should be static and not dynamically created, wherever possible. But wherever you're logging your imported object, you're logging it long before the async call finishes to fetch them, so it will log an empty object. This object may be populated if you check again much later in a setTimeout. A better design would be a loadControllers method that returns a promise that a consumer can call, and get controllers in an `await` or `.then()`

Comment: Yeah, the async/await you've sprinkled throughout the code here are not required. `readdir`'s second argument is a callback and that is only called when the function resolves. Either way, you have a race condition here, as Andy mentions.

Comment: yeah, I think that I was aiming for just wasn't going to work. It's just one of those days where I'm not thinking very clearly. I ended up just dynamically requiring all controllers in my base routes file. Thanks for your input though, much appreciated.

Comment: I have similar code just don't user asynchronous methods when setting up like this. Use `fs.readdirSync()` instead. The `require` function is already synchronous. Yes, it is generally not advisable to use sync methods because it will block the thread but in this case you don't care because your process hasn't even started serving clients

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently use asynchronous operations to create things you're going to export.  The exporting happens synchronously, but at the time of export, your `controllers` object has not yet been populated with any properties.

Thus the module that imports you will get an empty object (that will eventually be filled in, but will probably be empty at the time they try to use it).

Since this is only module initialization code, a simple solution would be to use synchronous file I/O instead of asynchronous file I/O so the controllers object gets its properties assigned before you export it.

Module initialization is one of the few times that it's OK and perhaps even desirable to use synchronous file I/O in a server.  In fact, `require()` uses synchronous file I/O for the same reason.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const controllers = {};

const files = fs.readdirSync('./controllers');
files.forEach(file => {
    if (file !== 'index.js') {
        const i = path.basename(file).indexOf('.');
        const fn = path.basename(file).slice(0, i); 
        controllers[fn] = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
    }
});

module.exports = controllers;
```

---

P.S. your use of `async` and `await` isn't helping anything here.  You aren't awaiting a promise and the `async` function is still non-blocking so module.exports is still assigned and the module returns before any of your module export properties have been assigned.

Comment: @michaelalexander - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.